# What .NET version maps to the latest ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I just created a Blazor server side app in Visual Studio. The description for it says it used ASP.NET Core, which I want.

But in the project properties, the target framework is .NET 7.0. Shouldn't it be .NET Core 3.1? I'm assuming 7.0 is .NET Framework, not .NET Core. Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: MS stopped using the "Core" denomination with .NET 5. The latest old-style non-core .NET is 4.8. Everything after that is the new style .NET that started with .NET core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.NET 5**

.NET 5 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1. We named this new release .NET 5 instead of .NET Core 4 for two reasons:

- We skipped version numbers 4.x to avoid confusion with .NET Framework 4.x.
- We dropped "Core" from the name to emphasize that this is the main implementation of .NET going forward. .NET 5 supports more types of apps and more platforms than .NET Core or .NET Framework.

ASP.NET Core 5.0 is based on .NET 5 but retains the name "Core" to avoid confusing it with ASP.NET MVC 5. Likewise, Entity Framework Core 5.0 retains the name "Core" to avoid confusing it with Entity Framework 5 and 6.

**.NET 6**

.NET 6 delivers the final parts of the .NET unification plan that started with .NET 5. .NET 6 unifies the SDK, base libraries, and runtime across mobile, desktop, IoT, and cloud apps. In addition to this unification, the .NET 6 ecosystem offers:

- Simplified development: Getting started is easy. New language features in C# 10 reduce the amount of code you need to write. And investments in the web stack and minimal APIs make it easy to quickly write smaller, faster microservices.
- Better performance: .NET 6 is the fastest full stack web framework, which lowers compute costs if you're running in the cloud.

**.NET 7**

.NET 7 is the successor to .NET 6 and focuses on being unified, modern, simple, and fast. .NET 7 will be supported for 18 months as a standard-term support (STS) release (previously known as a current release).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-7

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's versioning of .net core and .net framework has changed from .net core 3.1 onwards.

That is to say, they are "unifying" .net framework and .net core into a single runtime/version.

.NET 5, 6, 7 are the next versions to .NET Core 3.1.

You should, under no circumstances, create projects using .net core 3.1 anymore as it is out of support.

You can check out [Microsoft's roadmap for .NET here.](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)

[This blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/july/csharp-net-reunified-microsoft%E2%80%99s-plans-for-net-5) also explain's Microsoft's plan to "unify" the two environments.